How to configure TLD files in IntelliJ?
I am working on a legacy java project, this project is usually configured with Eclipse but I am trying to configure it with IntelliJ IDEA.
The project is does not follow any convention for directory structure like web applications do because we started from a desktop application, we are using Apache Ant to build this project. Basically this project is simple java project. I successfully configured web facets, hibernate facets and libraries but one thing I can not configure is custom TLDs. We created our own tags in Custom.tld and we are including in jsp files by <%@ taglib prefix="cst" uri="../WEB-INF/custom.tld"%> but IntelliJ is unable to find reference for this file highlighting it as red. Actually this file is configs directory (it does not have any namespace url) and jsp files are in userviews. Both directories are sibling (Child of project main directory). We dont have WEB-INF directory but it is created after deployment and all the configurations in configs directory are copied there. So how do I Configure IntelliJ? This
IntelliJ should suggest the tags from custom.tld.

Where did you configure .tld files?

What do you mean? If you are asking about directory of custom.tld its /configs/

It is wrong location. What is the actual problem? Did you add your web facet to the project? Show your project structure in the project explorer.

Yes I added web facets. userviews directory is added as web resources directory. The configs folder is also added in web resources directory. We compile project using ant. Our project does not follow any convention like maven projects do. So we can put .tld files anywhere we want and then we have to write ant script which will copy it to designated folder in tomcat directory.

If you want to put files anywhere you want then why do you complain about IJ? It uses defaults and knows the designated locations apriory.

My complain is why is IJ unable to locate custom.tld even when I provide path relative to project structure.
e.g my jsp is in userviews and my custom.tld is in config directory. The userviews and config are sibling directories, so if put <%@ taglib prefix="cst" uri="../config/custom.tld"%> in my jsp then IJ should find the file, but it is not.

You use relative path but you don't know the base and cannot calculate an absolute path, so it just fails to find a file which is unknown location.
